# join() in Thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Why this code is printing:
Inside Thread1
Inside Thread2
And goes into something like infinite loop because it is not terminating.

```
class Thread2 extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread1 t = new Thread1();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("Inside Thread2");
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Exception occurred inside Thread2");
        }
    }
}
class Thread1 extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        Thread2 t = new Thread2();
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Inside Thread1");
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Exception occurred inside Thread1");
        }
        Thread t2 = Thread.currentThread();
        try{
            t2.join();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
public class DaemonThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread1 t = new Thread1();
        t.start();
    }
}
```

I am not able to understan how join is working

Comment: You have twice as many `Thread` variables here as you need.  Simplify, and you’ll probably see the problem yourself.

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by `join`ing `Thread.currentThread()`?

Answer (score 3):

> I am not able to understand how join is working.

It's really simple. `t.join()` does *nothing.* It keeps doing nothing until the thread `t` is finished, and then it returns. That's all there is to it.

You could also think of `t.join()` as being like `Thread.sleep(n)` except that, instead of sleeping until `n` milliseconds have elapsed, it sleeps until thread `t` is finished.

---

P.S., You wrote this:

```java
Thread t2 = Thread.currentThread();
try{
    t2.join();
}
catch(InterruptedException e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

That's going to sleep forever. `Thread.currentThread()` has a misleading name. It should be called something like `Thread.caller()` or `Thread.self()` or `Thread.me()`. It returns the `Thread` instance of the thread that called it.

When you wrote `t2.join()` you are saying, wait until `t2` is finished, but `t2` is the thread that's calling `t2.join()`. The `join()` call won't return until the thread is finished, but the thread cannot finish until the `join()` call returns. Some people call that a *self deadlock.*

Comment: Thank's a lot. You just cleared all of my doubts. Now I understand why it is something like an infinite loop. Because it is saying wait till the time it completes itself. So it is waiting for itself to get complete. Correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You're right this code will go into an infinite loop I see several reasons

-The main thread creates and starts a Thread1 object, which is a user thread.

- The Thread1 object creates and starts a Thread2 object, which is a daemon thread.
- The Thread2 object creates another Thread1 object, which is also a daemon thread because it inherits the daemon status from its parent.
- The new Thread1 object creates another Thread2 object, and so on. This creates a chain of daemon threads that keep creating new threads.
- The main thread calls join() on itself, which means it waits for itself to finish. This is a deadlock situation, because the main thread can never finish while waiting for itself.
- The JVM does not exit because there is still a user thread (the main thread) alive. The daemon threads do not prevent the JVM from exiting, but they also do not die until the JVM exits.

If you want to fix this you could try removing the join() call from the Thread1 class. This way, the main thread will not wait for itself and will finish its execution. The JVM will then exit and terminate all the daemon threads. Another possible solution is to make the Thread1 class a daemon thread as well, so that there are no user threads left when the main method ends. The JVM will then exit and terminate all the daemon threads.

Comment: third point is wrong; the `Thread1` created in `Thread2` is never started - the deadlock (4th point) is the problem